# Run jQuery after WooCommerce AJAX cart update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce:

I have some jQuery that loads on document.ready that effects the quantity input box.  Works great.

My issue is that when I update the cart/delete item, the jQuery needs to run again because the AJAX call kills it (refreshes it).  Is there some hook/filter I can add that will re-run my script again after a cart update?  Ive searched and can't find anything (or maybe I'm not aware of what I am looking for).

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The WooCommerce scripts have several custom jQuery events built in. Your own script can listen to these events and run your own code when they are triggered. The most obvious one for your case might be [`updated_cart_totals`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3919b8361da5c604230e4a1a02ef21adbe1eb2b3/plugins/woocommerce/client/legacy/js/frontend/cart.js#L161C22-L161C29) but `updated_wc_div` might also be helpful, I'm not sure without testing. Tested and works.

```
$( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
    //re-do your jquery
});
```

Jan 2024 Update: I assume this will *not* work with the Cart/Checkout blocks, but only with the traditional cart/checkout shortcodes.

Comment: You're awesome Helga.

Comment: thanks, worked only without any quotes around document.body

Comment: @helgatheviking Wich custom event triggers after adding a cross selling item to the basket?  "updated_cart_totals" or "updated_wc_div" does not work in this case? Thank you so much

Comment: @NewUser for a new question, best to create a new topic. :)

Comment: @helgatheviking - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/287461/132453 This is what i need. Thank you so much. best

Comment: I was so disappointed when I clicked the "custom events" link in this answer. I was hoping to find a documentation of all WooCommerce custom events. The second link proved more useful, but do one really need to sift through all WooCommerce JavaScript files to find the available custom events?

Comment: I don't know that there is a docu yet listing all the custom JS events. As far as I know, yes, you do have to sift through source code.

Comment: Has anyone else been able to get this to work recently, post Woo 3.0?

Comment: @Nathan the [trigger](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.2/assets/js/frontend/cart.js#L127) still exists so I presume it should still work.

Comment: @helgatheviking where i put this script? my concern is i want to redirect page when last item removed from cart

Comment: @BInjalPatel You would need to save this into a javascript file `something.js` and then use `wp_enqueue_script()` to load it properly in WordPress.

Comment: Still working Dec 2023!

Comment: just a comment/suggestion : with "The WooCommerce scripts have several custom events built in"... the link on "custom events" misleads me into thinking i will see a webpage of woocommerce events listed when i click it... not an article about jQuery custom events

Comment: Inclined to agree, but there isn't a woo document showing all the custom events in the legacy cart scripts.

Answer (score 9):

I also needed to run a function after user removes item from cart, and the above events `updated_cart_totals` or `updated_wc_div` didn't work for me.

After digging into the **Woocommerce** frontend code

`[/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js]`

I found these events:

```
$(document.body).on('added_to_cart removed_from_cart', do_magic);
```

These worked like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

In my case I have to add the following:

```
jQuery(document.body).on('removed_from_cart updated_cart_totals', function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

Because I have a huge customization with js cart submit

Comment: Just make sure to add it in the functions.php file using wp_footer hook!