# Jquery trigger for remove product from woocommerce cart ajax

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking to run some jQuery when a product is removed from the cart in woocommerce. I thought this would do it, but it's not happening.

Any ideas?

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_wc_div', function(){
//magic
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run jQuery after WooCommerce AJAX cart update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312360/run-jquery-after-woocommerce-ajax-cart-update)

Answer (score 5):

There can be also triggered `updated_cart_totals` event when cart has updated. So, you can use the following workaround, as there is no one global event which triggered when the cart is updated:

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_wc_div', do_magic );
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', do_magic );

function do_magic() {
    // do magic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the product from cart using this code :

main.js

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/your_site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {action : 'remove_item_from_cart','product_id' : '4'},
    success: function (res) {
        if (res) {
            alert('Removed Successfully');
        }
    }
});
```

functions.php

```
function remove_item_from_cart() {
$cart = WC()->instance()->cart;
$id = $_POST['product_id'];
$cart_id = $cart->generate_cart_id($id);
$cart_item_id = $cart->find_product_in_cart($cart_id);

if($cart_item_id){
   $cart->set_quantity($cart_item_id, 0);
   return true;
} 
return false;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_remove_item_from_cart', 'remove_item_from_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_item_from_cart', 'remove_item_from_cart');
```

Comment: Question is to **trigger** jQuery action when **any item is removed** from cart not *how to remove an item from cart*.

Answer (score 0):

Give this set of code in  your js
file

```
jQuery(document.body)
  .on(
    'removed_from_cart updated_cart_totals',
    function() {
      // your code...
    }
  );
```