# Hiding Woocommerce message only fades out ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to fade out the WooCommerce message after some seconds, which is displayed when someone is updating for example the cart etc.

I'm using this code to get this done, which already works, but i found out that it only works once. So when someone is updating the cart for a second time (without refreshing the page), it's not fading out, so it stays there, like without the code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast') 
}, 6000);
```

Dev console shows no errors or something like that. How can i have it that it always fades out, no matter how often someone is updating the cart.

Comment: This should lead you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312360/run-jquery-after-woocommerce-ajax-cart-update/39321178. (I found it here: https://www.google.com/search?q=woo+commerce+cart+onupdate)